# Why are not all names recognized with Stanford NER?

Tags: python, stanford-nlp

I have written Python script with Stanford NER tagger. Due to space limitations I will present just part of the code
First,read file

```
lines=[]
with open('dialogue.txt', encoding='utf-8-sig') as outfile:
    for line in outfile:
        line = line.strip()
        lines.append(line)
```

Then expand contractions and remove spacial characters

```
def remove_special_characters(text, remove_digits=False):
    pattern = r'[^a-zA-z0-9\s]' if not remove_digits else r'[^a-zA-z\s]'
    text = re.sub(pattern, '', text)
    return text
```

My output so far

```
'[If we are all here let us get started First of all I would like you to please join me in welcoming Jack Peterson our Southwest Area Sales Vice President Thank you for having me I am looking forward to todays meeting I would also like to introduce Margaret Simmons who recently joined our team May I also introduce my assistant Bob Hamp Welcome Bob I am afraid our national sales director Anne Trusting cannot be with us today She is in Kobe at the moment developing our Far East sales force  Let us get started We are here today to discuss ways of improving sales in rural market areas First let us go over the report from the last meeting which was held on June 24th Right Tom over to you Thank you Mark Let me just summarize the main points of the last meeting We began the meeting by approving the changes in our sales reporting system discussed on May 30th After briefly revising the changes that will take place we moved on to a brainstorming session concerning after customer support improvements You will find a copy of the main ideas developed and discussed in these sessions in the photocopies posted in front of  you The meeting was declared closed at 1130 Petors is not coming todayprivate reasons  Thank you Tom So if there is nothing else we need to discuss let us move on to todays agenda Have you all received a copy of todays agenda If you do not mind I would like to skip item 1 and move on to item 2 Sales improvement in rural market areas Jack has kindly agreed to give us a report on this matter Jack  ]'
```

Now we use

```
nltk.tag.stanford.StanfordNERTagger
r=st.tag(doc.split())
for tag, chunk in groupby(r, lambda x:x[1]):
if tag != "O":
    print("%-12s"%tag, " ".join(w for w, t in chunk))
```

Final output

```
PERSON       Jack
LOCATION     Southwest
PERSON       Margaret Simmons
LOCATION     Kobe
LOCATION     Far East
PERSON       Jack
```

Not so good,same name like Anne,Tom or Petros have not been recognized. OK Petros is Greek name,but I can not find any explanation for the first two.

Comment: Your test string doesn't have any punctuation at all; have you tried fixing it up?

Comment: Yes,I have but it does not help.